# Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

I have six upvotes for the one question with no intervening history. They have been summarised into two groups - one with 4 events and one with 2 events. However, when you expand either, both show all 6 events. Minor I know, just letting you know.

[image: Reputation history]

Comment: Can you reproduce it *now*? This was reported several times, it is because of the asynchronous loading of the content...at least in 99% of the time.

Comment: Right now there is only one group item covering all 6 so it no longer presents in the same way.

Comment: Yeah.  After you expand a highlighted group of new votes on a certain post, when you reload the page, the new group merges with the older group.

Comment: I've had this before, it always disappeared on a refresh?

Comment: This still has not been fixed and @Rory it does not go away with a refresh/cache clear for me.

Comment: It also happens when there are seperate events which aren't normally included in the sub-list like removals... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193405/removed-points-are-listed-twice-in-rep-summaries

Comment: For what it's worth, this is still occurring.

Comment: Yeah, [I still have this bug as of today](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7FriF.png), so I guess it's been around for years without a fix.

Comment: One serious aspect of this issue is that if you switch between time/post mode, you get a timestamp in the URL, and at that point it doesn't matter if you refresh the page.

Comment: Reproduced again today on video.SE. See [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVt11.jpg) and [updated answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221220/212646).

Comment: I ran into this today too: https://i.snag.gy/rGoyFJ.jpg. Followed a nice chain of dupe links to this report.

Answer (score 17):

I've confirmed/reproduced the issue behind this. It is as I said. When you have new *and* old events on the same post in your history (only tested for the same day as well), both of them will expand to show the **full list** of all events for the post, rather than being limited to the new and old events as they're split up.

[image: New and old events combined]

They must have made a change somewhere that caused this to start happening, because it didn't used to do this previously.

Comment: I reproduced this in 2014, and again today. See my post below.

Comment: Reproduced this bug again today. [See my post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221220/212646).

Comment: [Reproduced this today as well.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event#comment944224_139091)

Comment: [Yet another repro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297101/incorrect-grouping-duplication-of-rep-events-when-unfolded?noredirect=1#comment963905_297101)

Comment: Still not fixed https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323538/260198

Comment: This bug still prevails for me today.

Comment: [still on in 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351006/178179)

Answer (score 7):

The below is what I saw just a few minutes ago (And have seen similar on quite a few occasions in the past). A couple of minutes later it has merged into one drop down with a correct total rep count.

I see Sulfurized Demonbobby [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/random-text-to-cause-comment-highlighting#comment391847_139091) above about the asynchronous nature of the updates, which I can understand if it was a a short while (a few minutes ago), but think it is unreasonable to have inaccurate counts (5 + 5 + 5 is 15, not 10) some *25 mins* after the event took place.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

February, <s>2016</s> **2017** and this bug is still scurrying about. It's not a big bug, but at least let us know if you're going to address it or not.

---

Most recent reproduction, found on video.stackexchange.com:

[image]

Blues and Reds should add up to each other. Greens are WTF.

---

Here is the Feb 2016 iteration:

[image]

On that post, I received 3 upvotes and 9 downvotes. You can see that the blue brackets are the same events, not different events, and the red stars list what's new, but appear to be incorrectly added because *all* events for the day are listed below, instead of just the new ones.

---

I reproduced this recently as well. [I made a different meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221194/212646), however, because I did not see this one first. The snapshot below is color coded to show where confusion might occur because of this. It did right itself about an hour later.

[image: Messed up rep events]

Comment: Some people who vote on meta are just stupid. The question is tagged as a bug, and it obviously is, and there is no response by se staff for over a year. My post proves that it is still happening and bumps this to the front page so people can see it again. Why would you downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I have just seen this issue... in fact it appears to have *two distinct symptoms* which appear in the UI:

- one of which could be considered an **enhancement-request**, as whilst the data displayed is not incorrect, it could be formatted better, and;
- the other could be considered a **bug** as it shows incorrect data

Here is the reputation with the unexpanded event - no *actual* error shown, except that it could be considered a UI **enhancement-request** as the reputation changes are not all contained under one expandable line, and it would be more aesthetically pleasing if they were:

> [image: Confusing rep change - contracted]

Here is the event expanded - this is the **bug** as it would suggest a reputation change of 11 rather than 6:

> [image: Confusing rep change - expanded]

Finally, after the page was refreshed, both issues appear to be, and indeed are, resolved:

> [image: Confusing rep change - contracted]

---

NOTE: I was going to post this as a *question*, but then realised that it would have been a duplicate (not that it matters *that* much) of this question and [Incorrect grouping/duplication of rep events when unfolded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297101/incorrect-grouping-duplication-of-rep-events-when-unfolded,However), when I saw that other people had posted similar experiences as *answers*, then I reasoned that I would do the same. I hope that was the correct thing to do - I've never raised an issue as an answer before and it seems rather counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

This OCD triggering bug still prevails!

[image]

Comment: If you are an OCD sufferer, then I feel your pain and I hope you have sufficient support mechanisms to manage it. But if not, would you please consider amending your answer as it may been seen as belittling a serious and debilitating mental health condition. May I suggest "This annoying bug" instead?