# How are reputation events grouped and counted?

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event)

The following image shows that I've got a group of 3 events with sum of 35. But there are 4 items in the group with the sum of 45. Besides the item that was left out is shown another time on the top of the day's events list (underlined with blue).

[image]

Is it a bug or what logic am I missing?

Comment: When you click on the expand arrow, the results you see are fetched real-time. So it will duplicate whatever (new) events are highlighted on top.

Comment: @animuson So is this by design?

Comment: The devs haven't said either way. All we know is a lot of people believe it's a bug, and we hope they fix it.

Comment: By the looks of it, it isn't a trivial fix. And it's so minor that it'll probably stay at the bottom of the to-do lists for a while.