# Odd accounting for reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event)

Twice today I have seen odd behaviour in my reputation page.  The first time, the same question was listed twice, once with 70 points, once with 75, but when the triangles were pressed to show the detail, both showed all the votes.  The second time (image below), the sum is supposed to be 30 but there are 6 events shown (despite the mention of there being 3 events); the question that first raised eyeborws is correct in the image.

[image: Unexpected accounting for reputation illustrated]

Is this really the way it is supposed to work?

(I carefully didn't show two downvotes that account for the two missing points.)

**Note**: I'm suffering from partial brain-death.  I've reached my daily limit, so some of those 6 events should be scoring zero points, I think.  The 30 is OK; the 3 events claim is not; and the extra 3 events shown should be scoring zero (or two should be zero and one should be two points to compensate for the downvotes).