# Duplicate entries in reputation detail

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event)

On [the Reputation tab of my ServerFault user page](https://serverfault.com/users/28400/miles-erickson?tab=reputation), I found that my answer to the question "How do I decide what type of hardware to use for a firewall?" received four upvotes yesterday. As you can see, the grouping isn't working quite correctly: instead of showing the question once with a summary reputation gain of +40, it is shown twice. Each summary heading reflects a net reputation gain of +20, but the sub-entries underneath that value do in fact add up to +40.

Each question should be presented once per day, with a single summary heading reflecting the total reputation impact.

[image: Screenshot showing 9,637 reputation, 39 earned yesterday. The same question "How do I decide what type of hardware to use for a firewall?" is shown twice, each time with a summary value of +20 above four "+10 upvote" sub-entries.]

Comment: I don't understand - Isn't there 2 lots of duplicates (i.e., 2 x 17:39, 2 x 17:46, 2 x 18:05, 2 x 18:21 with the header row listing a +20 score, for 4 x +10 scores (in each set)? Also, @AnnaLear - Where is caching mentioned in the question?

Comment: @user66001 It came up in the (now deleted) comments. I'm gonna clean up the rest to avoid confusion.

Comment: @AnnaLear - I presume you mean that it came up in the comments that were deleted before I commented? Do you happen to know if the issue described in the above, and in the referenced-as-duplicate-of question are in the process of being fixed?