# Minor reputation display issue

Tags: bug, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expanding an event group shows more events than labeled when there are new events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event)

This seems like some kind of bug to me. The same question appears to be splintered into two sets of events.

[image]

The /reputation tab shows the right data:

[image]

I'm sure in a few minutes this symptom will go away, but thought I would post it in case anyone else has seen it (especially today) and so that the devs are aware of it even if it is only transient.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, what search terms did you use to find the dupe? I did try before posting.

Comment: I used Google: `site:meta.stackoverflow.com double entry reputation tab`

Comment: Rule of the thumb: When searching for a dupe, always use google. The SE engine doesn't work too great.