# Reputation list bug

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, reputation

I posted a question on StackOverflow and got 3 upvotes on it, when I looked at my reputation list it was showing like this:

[image]

However when I pressed the arrow to see the "2" events this is what I got:

[image]

You can clearly see that there are 3 events inside of which one of them is a double of the bottom event. Is there any logic explanation that causes this miscalculation or is this a bug?

A couple of minutes later I noticed that the reputation is showing correctly and now shows like this (as it should):

[image]

Comment: My guess is caching.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Actually, in this it is a combination of caching and late loading. If you click the small arrow, it will load the actual list of events via AJAX, which will lead to such discrepancies.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event also, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159612/bug-when-viewing-reputation?lq=1