# Removed points are listed twice in rep summaries

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I had a [question with 1 upvote and 1 downvote which I removed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18220652/156755) (10k+).

On the rep page, it shows correct totals on the left hand side (should be +5/-2 and -3) but says `2 events` and lists 3, so the `removed` is listed twice.

To be clear, the actual rep change was correct - this is merely an issue of it being displayed incorrectly...

Either: The removed should be omitted from the first list (and the totals updated to +5/-5, 3 events) or the omitted from the first list. I'm guessing that the latter is what was intended

[image]

Comment: Looks like the same issue as [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event) except with a removed event instead of unseen events.

Comment: @animuson Possibly- but this remains after several refreshes and they're not being seperated into 2 groups for unseen/seen events. That said, I suspect it may be the same cause behind the scenes?

Comment: I'd imagine it has something to do with multiple event groups under the same day. The removed event will *always* be separated whether it's unseen or not. Expanding the event group probably just looks for *all* events with that post ID for that day, irrespective of whether that event is already displayed elsewhere, which is precisely what happens with unseen/seen event groups too.

Comment: @animuson Then I'll vote close dupe so if anyone else has a similar title to mine, they'll find the canonical answer - if you and others could do the same?