# The rep count for "today" has many issues

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, vote-count

Please refer to this snapshot of my English.SE profile rep page:

[image: Problems with today's rep count]

I have found six items that are confusing. I think they are by design, but they really fail on being intuitive and passing the user friendly bar. I have color coded them for easy reference.

- **Red** - The two red bars encapsulate the exact same thing. This reiteration implies that I have collected 10 upvotes and 2 downvotes for this question when I have actually collected half.
- **Orange** - The orange boxes show that the events count is not equal to the total below it. I presume that it relates to there being those events in the time block, but with all daily events listed below this looks like a count error.
- **Yellow** - The yellow boxes show that the number there does not equal the sum of what is listed below. Again, I think it is relative to the time next to it, but, again, this is confusing at best when the whole day's events are listed below it.
- **Green** - The total daily rep count in the green box is correct, but because of the reiterations, it does not equal the sum of the events below. Plus it looks like it is off by one for what it appears to be summing.
- **Blue** - This is a reiteration as well, though it shows different content.

My profile now shows correctly, but this has happened before on a different SE site (don't remember which one). I figured it was a fluke, but with it happening a second time I thought I should post about it.