# Incorrect grouping/duplication of rep events when unfolded

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

When accessing my profile and selecting the Reputation tab, my rep events are shown clustered by time with a fold-out button. Rep events that are close together in time are duplicated within these clusters.

[image: duplicate events]

If it matters: this image is taken from RPG.SE