# Incorrect reputation summary on profile page

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

> [image]

As you can see, it shows 2 events and +10 reputation. But there are 3 events below.

Comment: The two upvotes representing "1 hour ago" are the same. The bug lies in the fact that expanding the list also shows votes that are otherwise highlighted and shown separately as "new" changes. If you refresh the page, it will disappear as the vote is no longer "new".