# Odd rep display

Tags: bug, reputation, comments, ios-app

I had a comment, but there was no comment button.  Assuming I just hadn't joined the site, I thought, I'll put in an answer, which will join me, and then I can delete it and make it a comment.

It joined me to Math Overflow, but it still didn't give a comment option. Assuming it was a bug in the iOS app, I went to my laptop to fix it.

I deleted the answer and pasted the same text into a comment on the question. The reputation points of 115 dropped to 101. But the answer is on the rep list twice, with differing details. The list says I have 100, but it also says I have 101. If I add everything up, it is 100. But there is one downvote that had no effect (according to the list).

It sounds like a [bug(?) reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139091/expanding-an-event-group-shows-more-events-than-labeled-when-there-are-new-event) years ago, but I don't think this is "because of the asynchronous loading of the content" when a page refresh ten minutes later gives the same thing.

[image]

Comment: when a post is deleted, rep gained (or lost) from it is returned.

Comment: You always have one default reputation plus all earned. This means that with association bonus (100 rep) you will be at 101 rep. So everything seems fine to me.

Comment: But why does it show the -14 twice?  That would make the total 86.