# My reputation on Code Review shows an incorrect number of items in an expandable list

Tags: bug, reputation, design

This says it all:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62615/rory-ap?tab=reputation

[image]

Comment: Refresh the page, and try again. You'll see that it works now that the 22:52 event is not 'new' anymore. I'll leave it to the devs to say if it's [status-bydesign] or that their code needs some review ...

Comment: Thanks.  I doubt saying "3" and listing "4" is "by design", but we'll see.

Comment: @Glorfindel if it's the same as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139167/369802), I think by now the 'change' mentioned in that answer might be 'by design' ;)