# Incorrect rep sum when expanding score in reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, recent-activity

Incorrect rep sum when expanding score in reputation tab.

E.g. on https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1810/franck-dernoncourt?tab=reputation, I see `-10`:

[image]

but unfolding it shows `7*-1 = -14`:

[image]

Comment: It also says "6 events", which probably means it's counting 1 upvote and only 5 downvotes (and hence the +10/-10 score).